# When boost::lock_guard was moved

Tags: c++, boost

In which version of library `boost::lock_guard` was moved from "boost/thread/locks.hpp" to "boost/thread/lock_guard.hpp"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Checking the beautiful Boost online versioned documentation leads me to believe there was a change from version [1.52.0](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_52_0/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html#thread.synchronization.locks.lock_guard) to version [1.53.0](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html#thread.synchronization.lock_guard.lock_guard). I doubt it was "moved" though. It seems to me that including `locks.hpp` will now just include `lock_guard.hpp`.